# "WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable" when trying to download file in headless mode in linux

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run robot framework selenium python tests on Linux machine using Chrome in headless mode. All of the tests run fine until I hit a button to download a file. When I try to download a file the following error is thrown:

> "WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable  (Session info:
>   headless chrome=64.0.3282.140)  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139
>   (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux
>   4.9.27-14.31.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64)"

The same test works fine in windows though.

Below is the code I use to create the web driver session.

```
Launch Headless Chrome
    Create Download Directory
    ${chrome options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_argument    start-maximized
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --headless
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --window-size\=1920,1080
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --lang\=en-us
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
    ${prefs}       Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${download directory}    download.prompt_for_download=false   options.binary_location=/usr/bin/chromedriver
    Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome options}
    Enable Download In Headless Chrome    ${download directory}
    Go To   about:blank
```

Below is the code used to enable download behavior and setting the download directory for chrome headless.

```
def enable_download_in_headless_chrome(download_dir):
logger.info('Getting SeleniumLibrary Instance')
instance = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
driver = instance.driver
# add missing support for chrome "send_command"  to selenium webdriver
driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')

params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)
logger.info("response from browser:")
for key in command_result:
    logger.info("result:" + key + ":" + str(command_result[key]))
```

Comment: refer this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59678457/10262890

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following parameter `options.binary_location=/usr/bin/chromedriver` in :

```
${prefs}       Create Dictionary    download.default_directory=${download directory}    download.prompt_for_download=false   options.binary_location=/usr/bin/chromedriver
```

In *Python* bindings it is defined as follows and refers to the location of `chrome.exe` :

```
@property
def binary_location(self):
    """
    Returns the location of the binary otherwise an empty string
    """
    return self._binary_location
```

Change `options.binary_location=/usr/bin/chromedriver` to **`options.binary_location=/path/to/chrome`**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried  your suggestion and changed `options.binary_location=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` and also tried `options.binary_location=/usr/bin/google-chrome`. But this did not make any difference. If there was an issue with the binary location then even the normal test cases should not have worked right? In my case, the error happens only after hitting on download.