# Fail to download file with opened new tab in headless mode on Linux

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

As this answer by myself:
[How to download files headless in Selenium (Java) when download happens in new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59214185/how-to-download-files-headless-in-selenium-java-when-download-happens-in-new-t/59389494#59389494)

If download button trigger download action in opened new tab, I will switch to new tab and send command(as below code) to download file.

```
def enable_download_in_headless_chrome(self, driver, download_path):
    driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
    params = {
        'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior',
        'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_path}
    }

    driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

**I found that the above method failed on linux occasionally.**

When driver got the error, it would be crashed for a long time.
(I detect the situation from my error handling with retry.)

Error message:

> Message: timeout
>   (Session info: headless chrome=77.0.3865.120)

And I have looked at solution with the issue discussion but no one can solve it: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481

I guess the root cause is that I send enable download command before the new tab **in ready state**?

Please help me to find the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if there is a new tab is opened when you click on a download link (for example if it has `target="_blank"` attribute ). In such case download in headless with the enable_download_in_headless_chrome method, a solution doesn't work. So you can remove `target="_blank"` attribute by JS or get href and try to download by direct opening the link in the same tab.

if there is link and open in new tab then you can open in the same tab by overwriting javascript

```
def open_link_same_tab_download_file(current_user_driver, element):
    # open element in same tab add target to self
    current_user_driver.execute_script('arguments[0].target="_self"',element)

    # click on element to download file
    current_user_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element
```

if there is no link attribute then you can override javascript of open window in new tab like below

```
def open_new_tab_download_file(current_user_driver, element):
    # open element in same tab override javascript for that
    current_user_driver.execute_script('window.open = function(url) {window.location=url}')

    # click on element to download file
    current_user_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But the download button element not contains link and attribute 'target'.

Comment: @Yun please follow the above-edited answer. you can override js for an open window in the same tab.

Comment: I tried it. It's more stable than my method. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Linux,
I found that the file will be downloaded two times through below code:

```
# Open new tab by clicking download button
download_button.click()
# Switch to new tab
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
# Wait for ready state 
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')

##### The file will be downloaded to original download path ##### 

# Change download directory
enable_download_in_headless_chrome(driver, download_path)
# Refresh to trigger download behavior again
driver.refresh()

##### The file will be downloaded to your specific path again #####
```

If send "enable download" command before ready state,
it cannot change download directory successfully.