# selenium-webdriver File download pop-up when clicking on link opens a new window which converts to download box?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have all my settings to download files without the pop-up

```
def dl_driver(dl_path,display):
    pf = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    pf.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    pf.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    pf.set_preference("browser.download.dir", dl_path)
    pf.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                      "text/plain,text/x-csv,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/csv,"
                      "application/x-csv,text/csv,text/comma-separated-values,text/x-comma-separated-values,"
                      "text/tab-separated-values,application/pdf")
    if display.lower() == 'on':
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=pf)
    else:
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, firefox_profile=pf)
```

It works for most cases.

However I am facing a strange issue

When I click a link which pops open a new window and then the link being opened in that window converts to a '.csv' download prompt/box.

What should I change to make sure the download box/pop-up does not show up?

The HTML:

```
<button id="" class="was-btn was-btn-secondary was-my-downloads-download-btn" style="">Download</button>
```

As per the comment I should look for the `target` I am not sure about how to look for this. Is there a way to search for the target link? Or to open the clicked link in the same tab?

Comment: try to open link in the same tab by using target attribute of the link or you can JS for the open link in the same tab

Comment: @ManaliKagathara I can't see the target in the inspect element. Pasted above. Is there a way to find the target?

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59678457/10262890